# PROC SQL Update Efficiency for Large Datasets

Tags: sql, performance, sas, large-data

I have a SAS Master Dataset with 10 Million Rows and 1800 columns. I need to update 10 columns using a transaction dataset with 15 million records, only for records with matching key. 
I tried running a proc sql update statement using the following code.

```
proc sql;
UPDATE lib1.master1 a

SET col1 = (SELECT col1 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col3 = (SELECT col3 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col4 = (SELECT col4 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col5 = (SELECT col5 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col6 = (SELECT col6 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col7 = (SELECT col7 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col8 = (SELECT col8 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key),
    col9 = (SELECT col9 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE a.key=b.key)

WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM lib1.changes_1 b WHERE A.key = B.key);
quit;
```

I tried for just col1 for testing purpose and its been running for more than 4 hours.

I can think of data merge, by dropping the 10 columns and then a left join but that would change the column ordering. Reordering 1800 columns would again be a tedious task.

Is there a faster/more efficient technique?

Comment: FYI - SQL Update unfortunately as supported in SAS is almost always terrible.  SQL has many uses in SAS, but update should almost never be one, unless it's a single value update that's not sourced from a table.  For whatever reason, that _always_ seems to be incredibly slow, even for not-all-that-large datasets, and even for updates that in SQL Server are quite quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace one column, a format (roughly similar to Bendy's approach) is easiest.

To replace ten columns, always coming from the same row, I recommend a hash table.  Around the same speed as a single format, typically.  (Formats actually can be a bit slow at the 10MM rows mark, so this might be purely faster even than one.)

This took ~30 seconds on my laptop (CPU time, and real time; I have an SSD, so those are similar.  On a HDD this is probably 30 seconds CPU time and a few minutes real time.)

```
*make some dummy data;
data maindata;
  array col(10);
  do _i = 1 to dim(col);
    col[_i] = _i;
  end;
  do key = 1 to 1e7;
    output;
  end;
run;
data updatedata;
  array col(10);
  do _i = 1 to dim(col);
    col[_i] = 100+_i;
  end;
  do key = 1 to 3e7 by 2;
    output;
  end;
run;

*using MODIFY here which is identical in function to SQL UPDATE - does not make a new dataset;
data maindata;  
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash ud(dataset:'updatedata');
    ud.defineKey('key');
    ud.defineData('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10');
    ud.defineDone();
  end;
  modify maindata;
  rcUpdate = ud.find();
  if rcUpdate=0 then replace;
run;
```

Comment: I like this approach as it updates the dataset in place and uses hash tables to lookup the data.  Hard to beat that for speed when you have that many rows that require updating.

Comment: worked like magic!! it ran on a subset of 3 MM in 1 min.Many Many Thanks Joe, Never knew hash tables were this efficient. :)

Comment: Hash tables and formats are roughly equally efficient - both search in O(1) time.  Both have memory limitations of course - for a 10GB table you can't build a hash table without 10GB of RAM, and while I think formats still work they're sloooowww..

Answer (score 0):

You have a challenge.  First, I would suggest creating an index on `lib1.changes_1(key)`, if you do not have one.  That could be a big performance boost.

`proc sql` does not support `join` in updates -- that is what you really need.  However, many underlying data engines do.  So, if you are communicating to data in a database (such as MySQL, Postgres, or SQL Server), then you can write a native mode query to do the update with a `join`.

The all-SAS solution would be to use a data step.

Answer (score 0):

How about generating formats for each of the 10 columns in your transaction dataset `B`?

**Generate dummy datasets: `master` (10M records) and `transaction` (15M records) datasets:**
(The original `transaction` dataset is normalised below to prepare it for creating formats of each transaction variable)

```
data master ;
  do key=1 to 10000000 ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

data transaction(keep=start label fmtname) ;
  array t(10) col1-col10 ;
      do i=1 to 10 ;
        do start=1 to 15000000 ;
        fmtname=cat('COL',i,'F') ;
        label=cat('Column ',i,' has value ',start) ;
        output ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;
```

**Read in as formats:**

```
proc format cntlin=transaction ;
run ;
```

**Then applying the formats to the `master` dataset:**

```
data want ;
  set master ;
    col1=put(key,COL1F.) ;
    col2=put(key,COL2F.) ;
    col3=put(key,COL3F.) ;
    col4=put(key,COL4F.) ;
    col5=put(key,COL5F.) ;
    col6=put(key,COL6F.) ;
    col7=put(key,COL7F.) ;
    col8=put(key,COL8F.) ;
    col9=put(key,COL9F.) ;
    col10=put(key,COL10F.) ;
    output ;
run ;
```

Comment: This certainly seems a reasonable approach, though I think your actual implementation above needs to be cleaned up some.

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

1. Rollup `lib1.changes_1` into a temporary table (say, `lib1.changes_1_rolledup`) performing full scan. (`lib1.changes_1_rolledup`'s physical attributes should be carefully set up.)
2. Update `lib1.master1` with the `lib1.changes_1_rolledup`'s data performing full scan of one of the two and index scan of the other. (Which one to full scan depends on the actual data.)

## Explained

First, in order to achieve better performance you're most likely bound to go down to the underlying DBMS level and utilize its capabilities.

Then, the optimization technique really depends on the nature of your data.

I suppose [almost] all of the `lib1.changes_1(key)` values match one of the `lib1.master1(key)` values (`lib1.changes_1` may be even a detail table for `lib1.master1`). Also, we need to apply all the changes from `lib1.changes_1`. This means we have to read all the records from `lib1.changes_1` anyway. If so, the most effective way of doing this would be a `lib1.changes_1` table *full scan* but executed *only once*. This full scan would sum up all the changes from `lib1.changes_1` into a (possible temporary) table of such definition:

```
-- pseudo code:
create [temporary] table lib1.changes_1_rolledup 
  <set physical attributes depending on your data nature - see below>
  as select key, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
  from lib1.changes_1
  where 1 = 2
```

This rolled up changes table would likely contain no more than 10M records and depending of colX sizes may be relatively small in terms of storage space requirement. And what is more important, it would only have one record per `key` value which may be a great benefit.

The we need to assess how many of `lib1.master1`'s records are represented in `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` which in case of master-detail relationship is simply a comparison of record count.

If the `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` if only two-tree times (the rate actually depends on the DBMS) or less shorter than `lib1.master1` (in terms of record count), the most effective way would be to perform a full scan of `lib1.master1` updating every record from `lib1.master1` (all 9 `colX` values at once) with corresponding values from `lib1.changes_1_rolledup`. (The update with full scan should be implemented in a single update query whenever possible, of course.) In this case the physical attributes of `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` table have to be tuned for key lookup. I'd suggest technique similar to Oracle's index-organized table if available.

If the `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` is several times shorter than `lib1.master1`, then it is more efficient `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` updating the respective records from `lib1.master1`. The physical storage of `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` in this case should rather be tuned for full scan and possibly in the order of `lib1.master1(key)` appearance (which may be the case for auto-incremented surrogate keys, for instance).

P.S.
In order for simplify the description I omitted the cases where lib1.changes_1 contains only part of column updates for a certain key. This can be dealt with by adding flag fields in the `lib1.changes_1_rolledup` and tweaking the update as follows:

```
-- pseudo code:
update lib1.master1 m
  set m.col1 = (
        select case c.col1 then select c.col1 else m.col1 end
          from lib1.changes_1_rolledup c
          where c.key = m.key
      )
  ..............
```